# C# DateTime evaluation problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

So I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this logic.  It seems straightforward and my breakpoints indicate that the evaulation in the 'if' statement is resolving as True, but sum.ppStart et al aren't getting 14 days added to them.

It's probably something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

```
//Determine the start/end days of each week of the pay period and retrieve a list of those entries

DateTime[] weeks = timeTools.calcPP(0);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;

if (today > weeks[3])
{
  weeks[0].AddDays(14);
  weeks[3].AddDays(14);
  weeks[4].AddDays(14);
}

sum.ppStart = weeks[0];
sum.ppEnd = weeks[3];
sum.payDate = weeks[4];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AddDays` returns a *new* instance of `DateTime`, the existing value is not changed, it is an immutable structure. When using the function, capture the result

```
DateTime myDate = ...
myDate = myDate.AddDays(14);
```

Comment: Aww, I feel like a moron.  It's not like I've never done this before, haha.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Just to add to this - `DateTime` is immutable, just like `String`. The original question is a common mistake made with both of these.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you're not using the result of the `AddDays` method. The signature is

```
 public DateTime AddDays(double days)
```

or so (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)). You need to do this:

```
weeks[0] = weeks[0].AddDays(14);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the values:

```
if (today > weeks[3])
{
  weeks[0] = weeks[0].AddDays(14);
  weeks[3] = weeks[3].AddDays(14);
  weeks[4] = weeks[4].AddDays(14);
}
```